# Scheme List of lists zipping

Tags: recursion, scheme

If my input is a list of lists, then I want to output a list with elements from the input so that they are shuffled like a deck of playing cards.

For example, if input is '((1 2 3) (4 5)) then I want output to show up as '(1 4 2 5 3).

My idea is to first remove an element from the first list inside of a list, and then move that list of a list to the back of the list. This way, the first element of the next list of a list can then be appended.

Here is my code so far:

```
(define (shuffle ls)
   (if (null? ls) '()
       (cond ((null? car (ls)) (append (cdr (ls)) (list (cdr(car(ls)))))))
             (else (car (car (ls)))
                   (append (cdr (ls)) (list (cdr (car (ls))))
                   (shuffle (cdr (ls)))))))
```

Comment: What you're describing is zipping, not shuffling. Shuffling is non-deterministic (based on the output of a random function). Zipping is always deterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All the code snippets here require [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) to be loaded first.]

What you seem to be wanting is to zip the lists:

```
> (zip '(1 2 3) '(4 5))
((1 4) (2 5))
```

However, as you can see, this stops when it gets to the end of the shortest list. Maybe you can write a custom zip that will stop after all elements are exhausted:

```
(define (my-zip l1 l2)
  (cond ((and (null? l1) (null? l2)) '())
        ((null? l1) (cons (car l2) (my-zip l1 (cdr l2))))
        ((null? l2) (cons (car l1) (my-zip (cdr l1) l2)))
        (else (cons* (car l1) (car l2) (my-zip (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))))
```

Let's try it out!

```
> (my-zip '(1 2 3) '(4 5))
(1 4 2 5 3)
> (my-zip '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6 7))
(1 4 2 5 3 6 7)
```

Comment: I don't know if the list can be flattened first. I want to put the elements in the order in regards to how the lists inside the list is distributed. Flattening it first seems like it would be difficult to shuffle afterwards in the correct order.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I see, you're trying to zip the two lists. That's easy (with [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)). I'll update my post soon.

Comment: My post is updated now. You should try out the code and see if it does what you expect. :-)

Answer (score 0):

this would work too... i use chicken scheme so i have to "import" filter from srfi-1.

```
(use srfi-1)
(define *deck* '((1 2 3 4) (5 6 7) (9 10 11 12)))

(define nullcar? 
  (lambda (x) 
    (if (not (null? x)) 
      (null? (car x)))))

(define nullcdr? 
  (lambda (x) 
    (if (not (null? x)) 
      (null? (cdr x)))))

(define notnulls 
  (lambda (x) 
    (filter (lambda (e) 
              (not (null? e))) 
            x)))

(define firsts 
  (lambda (l) 
    (if (not (null? l)) 
      (map (lambda (x) 
             (if (not (null? x)) 
               (car x) 
               '())) 
            l))))

(define shuf 
  (lambda (d) 
    (notnulls 
      (append (firsts d) 
              (if (not (nullcar? d)) 
                (if (not (nullcdr? d))  
                  (shuf (map cdr (notnulls d))) 
                  '()) 
               '())))))
```

cheers!